# Data-role = "none" ignores my css styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile in a website I'm building, and wanting to remove the annoying styling on an *anchor tag*. When I add `data-role="none"`, it gets rid of the jQuery Mobile theme, but decides to ignore my:

```
float:right;
```

So now I have a situation where I'm left with an image in the completely wrong place.

Comment: Can you try `data-enhance="false"` instead of `data-role = "none"`?

Comment: @DavidR Does nothing for me but reverts it to the jQuery theme.

Comment: You mean it still ignores your `float:right` thing?

Comment: @DavidR Yes it does, but also adds the jQuery Mobile Styling

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile? What other frameworks are you referencing? Show us your markup for the Anchor.  Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/GqaXrd, can you edit it to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @ezanker It is an img inside an a tag inside a data-role = "header". Does this make any difference? Because when I used your codepen it didn't float right at all.

Comment: In the header, the easiest way is to give the a tag a class of ui-btn-right: <a href="#"  data-role="none" class="ui-btn-right"><img src="https://placeimg.com/20/20/tech" /></a>  Updated codepen  http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/GqaXrd

Comment: @ezanker That solved it! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but you can try to use

`float: right !important;`